# Basic trouble with for-loop in C

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm incredibly new to C programming [last night my husband decided to make me turn an assignment in pseudo-code into a working C program...] so I apologize for how simple this might be. I'm also new to stackoverflow, so please let me know if I've made any basic mistakes.

I've written the following:

```
 int CalcPower(int n, int m)
{
    int result = 1;
    int i;
    if(m = 0);
    result = 1;
    if(m = 1);
    result = n;
    for (i = 2; i <= m; i++);
    {
        result = result*n;
    }
    return result;
}
```

But I ran it with the numbers (2,4) and (2,8) and the result comes out 4 no matter what.
Where is my mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: Your mistake is that you didn't make any effort to go through a basic C language guide and you didn't debug your code.

Comment: Why assign after `if(m==0)`? you know the answer if `m` is 0, so just return it: `if(m == 0) return 1;` and `if(m == 1) return n;`

Comment: You may want to use ready C method called pow(). Please see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_pow.htm

Comment: @kamilw Naw, that's for floating-point values. You do not want to use it for integer operations.

Comment: @H2CO3 Good point, thank You. :)

Comment: @KamilW. No problem. I suggest you read the article "what every computer scientist should know about floating-point", it's very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, a couple of things, first those others have adressed in their answer, too:

- you're using the assignment operator when you want the comparison operator: `=` assigns, `==` compares.
- A semi-colon is the end of a statement, `;` is an empty, yet valid statement so `if(m ==0);` is saying: *"if m is 0, do nothing"*. Your `for` loop suffers from the same issue.
- As I said in my comment: why assign if you know the answer: `if(m==0) result = 1;` is a tad redundant, IMHO, I'd just write `if (m == 0) return 1;`

Now, something else:
You're computing an int, to the power of another int. Technically, 2^33 should be *"computable"*, but an int simply isn't big enough. Here's an alternative suggestion:

```
long long calc_power(int i, unsigned int exp)
{
    long long result;
    if (exp == 0) return 1;
    result = i;
    for (--exp;exp;--exp) result *= i;
    return result;
}
```

I've also removed the `if (exp == 1)`, as the way the loop is written, it can now deal with that.
Statements worth explaining:

```
long long calc_power(int i, unsigned int exp)
```

I've changed the function's signature a bit: it now returns a `long long` value, to accomodate the larger values, which a *power of*-function may return. I've also declared the second argument to be an `unsigned int`, to avoid having to deal with negative powers. Your function wasn't ready for that, but you didn't check to see if `m < 0`, you just *assumed* it was valid input.

```
if (exp == 0) return 1;
```

Note: No semi-colon after the closing parentheses

```
result = i;
```

This will promote the int to a `long long` value, and automatically assigns i^1 to `result`.

```
for(--exp;exp;--exp) result *= i;
```

There's a lot going on here. For a start, the loop begins with `--exp`, which is the same as `exp -= 1`, or `exp = exp -1;`.
The condition for the loop to continue is simply `exp`. This evaluates to false if `exp` is 0. Suppose `exp` was 1, then beginning the loop automatically sets `exp` to 0, and the loop is never entered. If `exp` was > 1, then the loop continues, decrementing `exp` until it, too, reaches zero.
On each iteration `result *= i;`, which is short for `result = result * i` is computed.
After all this is done, `return result` returns a `long long` value...

As H2CO3 pointed out, this snippet can be simplified even more:

```
long long calc_power(int i, unsigned int exp)
{
    long long result = 1;//assign 1
    for (;exp;--exp) result *= i;
    return result;
}
```

Instead of checking for an `exp == 0`, just assigning 1 to `result` from the get-go, and taking things from there will do just fine...
Note that `for(;exp;--exp)` isn't a typo. The first semicolon has to be present, but there's no expression that needs evaluating there. If you find `for (exp;exp;--exp)`, that works, too.

*Note:*
By no means is this function *"ready for production"*, this is just a basic example of how one might calculate `i1^i2`, for a more complete example of a `pow` function, have a look [here](http://www.open64.net/doc/db/d6e/pow_8c-source.html), and see if you can work out how the code works. You'll probably need some more info, and perhaps a book on the C language, though

Comment: you don't need to check the exponent for 0 explicitly. Just assign 1 to the result, then iterate from 0 to the exponent, multiplyijg the result with the base.

Comment: @H2CO3: Right indeed. I was too hung up on not assigning unless I was really going to use the var, I didn't think about that. Added a shortened version of the calc_power function without the `if`'s

Answer (score 4):

```
if(m = 0);
result = 1;
```

is equivalent to

```
if(m = 0)
    ;
result = 1;
```

You need to remove the `;` from the end of your `for` statements.

You also need to use `==` for comparison.  `m=0` assigns `0` to `m` then returns `0`, causing your `if` condition to fail.

```
if(m == 0)
    result = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Also for-loop

```
 for (i = 2; i <= m; i++); should be for (i = 2; i <= m; i++){ ...
```

You're for-loop will run from `i = 2 to m` incrementing, but it cannot reflect what logic intended to perform under it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
for (i = 2; i <= m; i++);
```

You need to remove the `;` from the end of this line; at the moment, it's just effectively this:

```
for (i = 2; i <= m; i++)
    /* No instructions to execute */;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Semicolon ends the statement;

`if ( / * Some condition * /);`

basically mean `if(/*whatever*/)` do  `;` i.e. nothing
instead of

```
if(/*Something*/)
/*i do it my way*/ ;
```

or better

```
if(/*Something*/)
{
/*i do it my way*/ ;
}
```

1. = is assignment, == is equal to tester

   if(m = 1);

This means assign `1` to `m` 
[Assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_assignment) returns the RHS so it turns into

```
if(1)
{

}
```

which means `if(true)`

Answer (score -1):

`if(m = 0);` means you are assigning 0 to the variable m so it will never be true.also you are putting a **`';'`** in your if statement so the statement after the if will not be affected by the condition.

```
'=' is an assignment operator

'==' is the comparison operator


int CalcPower(int n, int m)
{
    int result = 1;
    int i;
    if(m == 0)
    result = 1;
    if(m == 1)
    result = n;
    for (i = 2; i <= m; i++)
    {
        result = result*n;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: No, assigning 0 means it will *never* be true.

Comment: @unwind ah sorry that was a silly mistake.i updated my answer.you are right assigning 0 means the condition will always be false.